# how to increase the android 's sms sending throtle in delphi?

Tags: android, delphi, sms

I can send SMSs with code (Delphi Rio) with `smsManager.sendTextMessage(destAdress, nil, StringToJString(memo1.Text), nil, nil);` but i want to send the same SMS to 200-300 members without the android's restriction of 30 SMSM/30 minutes.
Somewhere i read that this throttle can be changed through ABD commands.
Is there a way to do it with Delphi code ?

PS. must I add a delay in the `for i:= 0 to numOfReceipients` loop ?

Comment: Not in code no. An article on it: https://www.xda-developers.com/change-sms-limit-android/

Comment: @brian. This article I had read. I hoped that it could be possible with delphi code